# C++ - Eclipse message ld: can't link with a main executable file './src/Chapter01.o' for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm currently learning cpp and have installed the Eclipse IDE on Mac OSX. When I renamed the file `HelloWorld.cpp` into Chapter01.cpp, the compiler is showing me this error:

```c
Building target: Hello World
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
g++  -o "Hello World"  ./src/Chapter01.o   
ld: can't link with a main executable file './src/Chapter01.o' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Hello World] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

please let me know how I can fix it, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding from scratch? By removing any executable, object or any other file generated by the build procedure?

Comment: No, do you mind telling me how should I do that ? Do I need to go directly to the file directory?

Comment: Doesn't Eclipse have some kind of "Rebuild" or "Clean" option? I don't have Eclipse, and haven't used it in many years, but IIRC it should have something like that. Otherwise just remove the files directly.

Comment: You're right, there is a Clean option. I just tried it and it doesn't work, guess i'll just download another IDE